# PHP List Directory structure and exclude some directories

Tags: php

I have this PHP Code:

```
$rootpath = '../admin/';
$inner = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootpath);
$fileinfos = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($inner);

foreach ($fileinfos as $pathname => $fileinfo)
{
    $pathname2 = substr($pathname,2);
    $sql = "SELECT * from admin_permissions where page_name = '$pathname2'";
    $rs = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
    if (mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0)
    {
        if (!$fileinfo->isFile()) continue;
        $sql2 = "INSERT into admin_permissions (page_name) values ('$pathname2')";
        $rs2 = mysql_query($sql2,$conn);
        echo "$pathname<br>";
    }
}
```

That is displaying my directory structure and inserting the directories and file names into a database (removing the first 2 characters `..`).

Since the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` iterates through all files in all directories, how can I exclude whole directories, including all files within them?

Comment: `if ($pathname == $dontWant) continue;` Or use a `FilterIterator`. Or so many other possibilities.

Comment: i want to exclude all files in a directory not just chosen files

Comment: Well, that's counter to what you say in the question. But check for `$fileinfo->isDir()`/`isFile()` instead then, which you already seem to be doing. I'm not sure what the question is here really.

Comment: read what i have put 'whats the best way i can exclude some directories from being inserted?'

Comment: Now I see what you mean. I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 28):

In essence, my answer is not much different from [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20266387/538216)' answer. However, he does not get a few things correct:

- The semantics correct for the `RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator` require you to return `true` to recurse into subdirectories.
- He doesn't skip the `.` and `..` directories inside each sub-directory
- His `in_array` check doesn't quite do what he expects

So, I wrote this answer instead.  This will work correctly, assuming I understand what you want:

<sup>Edit: He has since fixed 2 of those three issues; the third may not be an issue because of the way he wrote his conditional check but I am not quite sure.</sup>

```
<?php

$directory = '../admin';

// Will exclude everything under these directories
$exclude = array('.git', 'otherDirToExclude');

/**
 * @param SplFileInfo $file
 * @param mixed $key
 * @param RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator $iterator
 * @return bool True if you need to recurse or if the item is acceptable
 */
$filter = function ($file, $key, $iterator) use ($exclude) {
    if ($iterator->hasChildren() && !in_array($file->getFilename(), $exclude)) {
        return true;
    }
    return $file->isFile();
};

$innerIterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
    $directory,
    RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS
);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator($innerIterator, $filter)
);

foreach ($iterator as $pathname => $fileInfo) {
    // do your insertion here
}
```

Comment: although probably intentional, this will exclude both `/root/path1/otherDirToExclude` and `/root/path2/otherDirToExclude`

Comment: This is a great solution if you have unique directory names, but adding absolute paths or relative paths to $exclude doesn't appear to work as I would expect.  Still a good solution though.

Answer (score 12):

I suggest using the RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator.

```
$directory = '../admin/';
$filter = array('.git');

$fileinfos = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
  new RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
      $directory,
      RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS
    ),
    function ($fileInfo, $key, $iterator) use ($filter) {
      return $fileInfo->isFile() || !in_array($fileInfo->getBaseName(), $filter);
    }
  )
);

foreach($fileinfos as $pathname => $fileinfo) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: I'd probably extend `RecursiveFilterIterator` and override the `accept()` method rather than going for the callback variant. Personal preference I guess. Either way I think using the Spl iterators is the most correct way to do it, so +1.

Comment: I was about to upvote this, but your answer won't actually work for several reasons so -1 instead.

Comment: I tested with a positive check (less results) and forget the add the ! back. The return of the function is a boolean. Good point with the ".", ".." entries.

Answer (score 3):

I feel that some of the other answers are good, but more verbose than they need
to be. Here is a some simple code. My example only filters the `.git` directory,
but you can easily expand it to other items:

```
<?php

$f_filter = fn ($o_file) => $o_file->getFilename() == '.git' ? false : true;
$o_dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.');
$o_filter = new RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator($o_dir, $f_filter);
$o_iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($o_filter);

foreach ($o_iter as $o_file) {
   echo $o_file->getPathname(), "\n";
}
```

https://php.net/class.recursivecallbackfilteriterator

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to try using Symfony's finder library as it makes alot of this much easier and is easily installed via composer here are the docs

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html

and here is a simple example of something similar to what i think you're asking

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

/**
 * @author Clark Tomlinson  <fallen013@gmail.com>
 * @since 12/6/13, 12:52 PM
 * @link http://www.clarkt.com
 * @copyright Clark Tomlinson © 2013
 *
 */

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$finder = new Finder();
$directories = $finder->directories()
                      ->in(__DIR__)
                      ->ignoreDotFiles(true)
                      ->exclude(array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four'))
                      ->depth(0);

foreach ($directories as $dir) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($dir->getRealPath());
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

That example will return all directories without transversing into them to change that change or remove the depth.

To get all files in that directory do something similar to this

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

/**
 * @author Clark Tomlinson  <fallen013@gmail.com>
 * @since 12/6/13, 12:52 PM
 * @link http://www.clarkt.com
 * @copyright Clark Tomlinson © 2013
 *
 */

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$finder = new Finder();
$directories = $finder->directories()
                      ->in(__DIR__)
                      ->ignoreDotFiles(true)
                      ->exclude(array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four'))
                      ->depth(0);

foreach ($directories as $dir) {
    $files = $finder->files()
                    ->ignoreDotFiles(true)
                    ->in($dir->getRealPath());

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($file);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use RecursiveFilterIterator to filter dirs and in fooreach loop you have only accepted dirs.

```
class MyDirFilter extends RecursiveFilterIterator {
    public function accept() {

        $excludePath = array('exclude_dir1', 'exclude_dir2');
        foreach($excludePath as $exPath){
            if(strpos($this->current()->getPath(), $exPath) !== false){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;

    }
}

$rootpath = '../admin/';
$dirIterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootpath);
$filter   = new MyDirFilter($dirIterator);
$fileinfos   = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($filter);

foreach($fileinfos as $pathname => $fileinfo)
{
    // only accepted dirs in loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it simpler, with some basic php functions, easy to read (no thirty part, no delegations to other objects), and this few lines.

First, you create a function,that receives the dir you want to explore, 
and an optional array or excluded filenames

```
function getFiles($dir , $exclude=array()){  
    $acceptedfiles=array();  
    $handle=opendir($dir );
    //reads the filenames, one by one   
    while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
        if ($file!="." && $file!=".." && is_file($file) && !in_array($file, $exclude)) 
        $acceptedfiles[]=$file;
    }
    closedir($handle); 
    return $acceptedfiles;
}
```

Now, you just have to call the function

```
$files= getFiles($rootpath) ;
```

or if you want to exclude some files if they exist, you can call

```
$files= getFiles($rootpath, array(".htaccess","otherfile", "etc")) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
$excludes = array(
    'files' => array('file1.ext','file2.ext','fileN.ext'),
    'dirs' => array('dir1','dir2','dirN')
);

foreach ($directories as $current_dir) {
    if (!in_array($current_dir,$excludes['dirs'])) {
       // directory method
       foreach ($files as $current_file) {
            if (!in_array($current_file,$excludes['files'])) {
              // files method
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work recursively, but otherwise I like the simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

If I correct guess you then you just want add to base only path for files, not for directory.

Just use for check function `is_file` in your foreach

For example

```
foreach ($fileinfos as $pathname => $fileinfo)
{

    if (!is_file($pathname)) 
    {
         continue;// next step
    }
    $pathname2 = substr($pathname,2);
    ...
}
```